# Remembering changes made by a custom function

Tags: r

let's say I have a blank matrix

`blank <- matrix(,3,3)`

now, I want to populate the specific elements of the matrix, and being too lazy to type `blank[row, col] <- value`, I wanted to create a custom function

```
populate <- function(row, col, value) {
     blank[row, col] <- value
     return(blank)
}
```

So when I input `populate(1,1,5)` it returns the desired output, but the output is not stored under the object `blank` i.e, next time I input `populate(1,3,2)` I want `blank[1,1]` to show 5 and `blank[1,3]` to show 2 but only the latter happens i.e, the first command is forgotten.

How do have my custom function make permanent change to the object `blank`?

Comment: Try with `blank <- populate(...`

Comment: use a matrix of row/col indices: `m <- rbind(c(1, 1), c(1, 3)); blank[m] <- c(5, 2); blank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want is with `<<-` inside your function. Then, when you assign value, it occurs in the calling environment.

```
blank <- matrix(,3,3)
populate <- function(row, col, value) {
     blank[row, col] <<- value
}
populate(1,1,5)
populate(1,3,2)
blank
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   NA    2
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```